# Проблема с Source Control в Visual Studio Code под Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, git, visual-studio-code

Я использую Visual Studio Code на Ubuntu, и с недавнего времени  начались проблемы с контролем версий, суть которых заключается в том, что происходит нечто вроде рассинхронизации в видимом состоянии репозитория между нормальным консольным git и средой vscode. Чаще всего такая проблема возникает после обновления состояния репозитория через консольный git - commit/reset/revert/rebase и пр. Результатом этой фичи/баги становится то, что через vscode я вижу изменения, которых не видит консольный git, или наоборот.

Уже потратил кучу времени на гугление и попытки заставить vscode работать нормально. Пробовал отключать контроль версий в настройках vscode, пробовал удалять все расширения, переустанавливать приложение - результата нет. В качестве временного решения помогает только переключение на другой рабочий каталог и обратно, но делать это после каждого изменения состояния репозитория уже надоело.

Если кто-то сталкивался и смог избавиться от этого, подскажите, как?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), в первую очередь обратите внимание на заголовок: сейчас он минимально информативный.

Comment: Я пользуюсь SO более 10 лет, и если бы он работал нормально, я бы зашел через свою учетную запись, но не могу, потому что получаю внутреннюю ошибку.

Comment: После изменений через командную строку жмите круговую стрелку (Refresh) в vscode в панели source control: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3hnE.png. Как я понимаю, vscode не отслеживает в фоне состояние гита, только обновляет свое состояние когда сам же изменения вносит (ну и при открытии).

Comment: Кнопка Refresh ничего не делает. В списке изменений указано 0 изменений. В файле с изменениями зелеными полосами отмечены линии с изменениями, которые не видно через git. Судя по всему, это вообще нормально не работает. Есть ли способ заставить vscode не вести контроль версий?

Comment: Кнопка вполне работает. Возможно какой-то баг проявляющийся на вашей конфигурации. Пробуйте писать issue в проект vscode.

Comment: Спасибо, я лучше возьму другой редактор.